# Maximum Storage Capacity for a Laptop

Tags: hard-drive, laptop, windows-10, ssd, acer-aspire

this is my first question on superuser,

I bought an acer laptop about 1,5 years ago, an acer v3-772G with quite good specs, except for the hardrive.

I currently have the preinstalled SATA 2.5" 1000GB HDD, which is running at about 5400 RPM.
I am running out of storage at a high speed, and the hard drive itself is really slow. (I tried reindexing, defragmenting, formatting etc...)

Now, I have contacted ACER support, and they told me I have a second drivebay (in which I plan to put a 256GB SSD), and that the specs of the current HDD are the MAX specs this model supports.
Now, I think that's just incorrect seeing as I have a intel i7-4702MQ quad-core processor, 8GB ram, a GTX850M with (according to dxdiag) 6GB of total video memory.

I really want to get a 2TB + HDD together with an SSD, so is what the customer support rep told me true? and does the second drivebay of my laptop have a lower speed than that of the primary one?

Hope you guys can help e out!

Comment: Your CPU and whatnot are not related to the storage controller in any way. ;) That being said, there’s nothing larger than 2 TB anyway.

Comment: @DanielB Alright, so as long as I use the same format and possibly a higher RPM, my motherboard should still accept it?

Comment: Nah, just go ahead and get a 2 TB drive, it’ll most likely work. Just remember to provide an answer when you tried it, so others will know, too. Answering your own question is acceptable and encouraged.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have figured it out...

I got myself a 2TB 5400RPM 2.5" HDD from a friend to test it out, and while screwing open the case anyways (laptop) I also got to put a nice little SSD inside of the second drivebay :)

Comment: The system really shouldn't care about the size of the disk. SATA controllers are fine with disks of pretty much arbitrary size so a 2 TB drive should fit in the machine without any issues. Also, are you sure the drive is 7200 RPM? The only 2 TB laptop hard drives I've seen are 5400 RPM.

Comment: @bwDraco Yeah, my bad, I was busy with desktop drives in my mind... edited it :)